# Cookie not set when localhost web app accesses remote API

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

I have a React web app served on `http://localhost:3000`.

This web app accesses a remote API i.e. `https://app.example.com/api`.

When performing a login on the API, the server returns a session Cookie like this one:

```
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=ZmQ2Yzg4OWYtYzdiNi00Mzc1LTkzMzUtYzhiZjZmM2MzZjMy; Domain=app.example.com; Path=/api/; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
```

However, on Chrome, the Set-Cookie doesn't appear in the list of response headers. Also, if I re send the same request, Chrome doesn't include the Cookie in the request headers.

So, my understanding is that it ignores the Cookie. Why?

Regarding CORS, I don't see any issue with it, and the request is sent correctly by Chrome. Here are the returned CORS headers in the preflight:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PATCH,GET,POST,PUT,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: ETag, X-XSRF-TOKEN
```

I tried adding a local DNS entry `app.me` pointig to `127.0.0.1` but still doesn't work.

I also tried with Edge, and I can see the Set-Cookie header appearing, however, the cookie doesn't appear to be set too.

---

**EDIT:**

This it the Axios code:

```js
const axios = require('axios');

const backendUrl = 'https://app.example.com/api';
const constructUrl = url => `${backendUrl}${url}`;

const axiosConfig = {
  withCredentials: true,
};

export default {
  get: url => axios.get(constructUrl(url), axiosConfig),
  post: (url, data) => axios.post(constructUrl(url), data, axiosConfig),
  put: (url, data) => axios.put(constructUrl(url), data, axiosConfig),
  delete: (url, data) => axios.delete(constructUrl(url), data, axiosConfig),
};

//And in a different file...

HttpService.post('/login', creds)
        .then((response) => {
          const userInfo = response.data;
          const token = response.headers['x-xsrf-token'];
          sessionStorage.setItem('user-info', JSON.stringify(userInfo));
          sessionStorage.setItem('user-xsrf-token', JSON.stringify(token));

          window.location.replace('/');
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          if (err.response.status === 401) {
            setLoginError('Bad cred');
          } else {
            setLoginError('Fail to auth');
          }
        });
```

Comment: What are you using to send the request to the API? Fetch?

Comment: @NicoleWhite I'm using AXIOS (https://github.com/axios/axios)

Comment: Did you set `withCredentials: true`?

Comment: @NicoleWhite Yes - it is set to true.

Comment: Would you mind editing your question to include the axios code you are using to perform the login?

Comment: @NicoleWhite Done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, for some reason, I can't make Chrome show cookies associated to other domains than the one mentioned inside the address bar. So, inside the address bar, I have `http://localhost:3000` and I'm not able to see cookies associated with `app.example.com`.
Also, the dev tools don't show the `Set-Cookie` (response) and `Cookie` (request) for the same reason. But that doesn't mean the cookie is not received and set.

However, in my case, the cookie wasn't set because of the presence of `SameSite=Lax`.

After removing this cookie attribute, the cookie is set and included in the next requests.